# wordpress debug notices still showing after disabling from wp-config

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, password-protection

I have disabled debug notices from wordpress's file wp-config as follows:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );
```

but, on the website, the notice is still showing on different pages. How to remove it?

following is the notice:

```
Notice: Undefined property: WP_Error::$ID in /home/kg9ipdgegpfr/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-user.php on line 170
```

website link: https://tresonetwo.com

Comment: do you have cache plugin enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you’ll change the following code:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

In either case, you need to replace this line with the following code:

```
ini_set('display_errors','Off');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL );
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```